# Check JSON root element

Tags: c#, json

I'm working with C#, trying to parse JSON to XML, but first i need to validate the JSON and then check if it have a root element, there is my problem.

Suppose I got these two JSON strings:

```
string jsonWithoutRoot = "{'name': 'Fran', 'roles':['Admin','Coder']}";
string jsonWithRoot = "{'person': {'name': 'Fran','roles':['Admin','Coder']}}";
```

I want to get TRUE if the string have a root element like jsonWithRoot and FALSE in the other case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JSON string has one root object by definition. You're simply trying to count whether this root object has only one element.

This is trivially done by parsing the JSON into a `JObject` and getting the element count:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
bool hasOneElement = jObject.Count == 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was having a misconception about what was a root element.

Answer (score 1):

I have been recently using this method to check what you are looking for. It might be helpfull.

```
public static bool HasOneProperty(string json)
{
   JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);

   if (jsonObj.Count > 1)
   {
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```